# Rails form helper number_field_tag size option not working in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Rails 4.1.1, Ruby 2.1.2, Twitter Bootstrap (bootstrap sass gem) 3.0.3. `Number_field_tag` shows the same size no matter what I set the `size` option to per the documentation saying that it can take the same options as `text_field_tag` (which has a `size` option).

Incidentally, just to test, I tried a `text_field_tag` and the `size` option works fine. Anyone know the fix here? I'm happy to use a CSS class to achieve the same effect, but why write extra code right?

Also note, when I inspect element, `size` is showing up, it's just not doing anything:

```
<input id="transaction__Portable_table" min="0" name="transaction[][Portable table]" size="1" type="number" value="0">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Input type="number" fields [do not support the size attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.number.html).  Use `:max` instead. For example, if you want to limit to 2 digits use:

```
number_field_tag :my_number_field, nil, min: 0, max: 99
```

Comment: Oh bummer... wish the docs had specified that more clearly then. Thanks!

Comment: The docs are flat out incorrect regarding this. https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/number_field_tag clearly states that "[number_field] accepts the same options as text_field_tag". Thank you infused for this clarification.